# NSCompositingOperation examples anywhere?

Tags: cocoa, core-graphics, appkit, nsimage, nscolor

I'd like to explore some of the more obscure `NSCompositingOperation` options, like `NSCompositingOperationColorDodge` and `NSCompositingOperationSoftLight` and so forth, to find the right way to implement a particular effect I want in my app.  All I can find about them is the AppKit doc, which has just a couple of words about each and seems to have no visual examples at all (as far as I have found, using Dash).  Google provides essentially nothing about them.  I did find a reference on one web page to an old Apple Developer example app called CompositeLab, but it doesn't seem to exist any more (indeed, Apple seems to have taken down *all* of their sample code and examples, or I haven't been able to figure out where they're hosted nowadays – what happened there??).  Ideally, I'd love to have an app (like I guess CompositeLab was) where you could provide a "source" and "destination" image (or just a color value for them, optionally) and see the result from each compositing option.  Does such a thing exist somewhere?  How are people meant to discover the utility of these options?  Or does nobody use them because nobody really knows what they do?

Comment: Some of the older types (unfortunately not the newer ones you mention above) are documented about half-way down here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/GraphicsContexts/GraphicsContexts.html

Comment: Apple has archived old documentation and sample code. developer.apple.com -> Documentation -> Documentation Archive -> search for "CompositeLab".

Comment: If the documentation doesn't help then try the header. `NSGraphics.h` refers to http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-compositing-1-20140220/#blendingseparable